# Creating an OutputStream with limited throughput

Tags: java, io

I'm pushing data from my Java application over a USB connection to an Arduino in the other end.

The Arduino is only capable of buffering 64 bytes of data at its end, so I have to limit how many bytes are sent in each 'gulp' from my Java app (excess bytes will be lost). When the Arduino code is prepared to receive more bytes, it will send a simple ping up the wire.

So, I've extended `BufferedOutputStream` in a class `ArduinoBufferedOutputStream`, which wrappes the actual output stream. From different parts of the Java app an arbitrary number of bytes are written to the stream (with `write(byte b)`), and the stream is occationally `flush`ed.

What I need (I guess) is to override `BufferedOutputStream`s flush method, so that it will not send more than 64 bytes, before receiving the ping from Arduino, at which time the stream should send 64 more bytes (or less).

```
     static class ArduinoBufferedOutputStream extends BufferedOutputStream {

        public static final int WIRE_CAPACITY = 25;
        private byte[] waiting = new byte[0];
        private int onWire = 0;

        public ArduinoBufferedOutputStream(final OutputStream wrapped) throws IOException {
            super(wrapped, 500);
        }

        public void ping() {
            this.onWire = 0;
            this.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            if (this.onWire >= WIRE_CAPACITY) {
                return; // we're exceeding capacity, don't to anything before the next ping
            }
            if (this.count > WIRE_CAPACITY) {
                this.waiting = new byte[this.count - WIRE_CAPACITY];
                System.arraycopy(this.buf, WIRE_CAPACITY, waiting, 0, this.count - WIRE_CAPACITY);
                this.buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(this.buf, 0, WIRE_CAPACITY);
                this.count = WIRE_CAPACITY;
            } else {
                this.waiting = new byte[0];
            }
            onWire += this.count;
            super.flush();
            if (this.waiting.length > 0) {
                System.arraycopy(this.waiting, 0, this.buf, 0, Math.min(this.waiting.length, WIRE_CAPACITY));
                this.count = Math.min(this.waiting.length, WIRE_CAPACITY);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't work properly. Bytes are lost if the buffer contains more than `WIRE_CAPACITY` bytes, as demonstrated by the following testcase:

```
@Test
public void testStream() throws IOException {
    final ArduinoBufferedOutputStream stream = new ArduinoDisplayOutputStream.ArduinoBufferedOutputStream(System.out);
    stream.write("This is a very, very long string, which must be made even longer to demonstrate the problem".getBytes());
    stream.flush();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
}
```

The following string is printed: `This is a very, very long string, which must be ma`, while I obviously would like the whole string to be printed.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?
Or even better, does anyone know of an existing library that does what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I got it right, finally. Extending `BufferedOutputStream` was a dead end. Instead, I use a separate buffer, like @ben-lawry suggested. And by using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` as that buffer, I can easily poll `WIRE CAPACITY` number of bytes on each `flush()`.

Not terribly efficient, one might say, but the stuff going on on the Java side will still be speedy compared to the Arduino processing.

Here's what I got:

```
   static class ArduinoBufferedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        public static final int WIRE_CAPACITY = 25;
        private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Byte> buffer = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Byte>();
        private int onWire = 0;
        private OutputStream wrapped;

        public ArduinoBufferedOutputStream(final OutputStream wrapped) throws IOException {
            super();
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int i) throws IOException {
            this.buffer.add((byte) i);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
            for (byte aByte : bytes) {
                this.buffer.add(aByte);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] bytes, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            for (int i = off; i < len; i++) {
                this.buffer.add(bytes[i]);
            }
        }

        public void ping() throws IOException {
            synchronized (this.buffer) {
                this.onWire = 0;
            }
            this.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            synchronized (this.buffer) {
                for (; this.onWire < WIRE_CAPACITY && buffer.size() > 0; this.onWire++) {
                    wrapped.write(buffer.poll());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks, @gpeche and @ben-lawry - it certainly helped getting a few more eyes on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I admittedly don't have any experience with Arduino, but I have a lot of experience with messing with Java Output/InputStreams.  Take this with a grain of salt, as I have no way to actually test this on a real Arduino device, but if I were in your situation, this is what I'd do.

I suspect your call to `stream.write("This is a very, very long string, which must be made even longer to demonstrate the problem".getBytes());` is actually buffering the entire string.  When you subsequently call `stream.flush()`, all of the string data gets "written" to the Arduino device all at once.  The reason I suspect this is because you're calling the `BufferedOutputStream` super constructor with a size of 500 bytes.  First, I'd try reducing that to 64-bytes.  However, I suspect this might not fix the problem either because `BufferedOutputStream` isn't going to know when to call `ping`.

I think you're going to want to override both `write` and `flush`.  The idea behind `flush`, according to the Java specification, is that `flush` is supposed to force any unwritten, buffered bytes to get written to the underlying stream:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()

I'd also probably just extend plain-ole `OutputStream` and do any buffering on my own.  I would override the `write` method to buffer up to 64-bytes of data at a time.  If 64-bytes isn't enough space, call `super.write()` on your filled 64-byte buffer, then call `super.flush()` and then `ping()`, prior to buffering/writing any more data.  Repeat this process in a while loop until your buffer has enough space to hold whatever's left of your input data.  Then override `flush` to write any data that didn't completely fill your underlying 64-byte buffer (and thus did not actually get written by previous calls to `super.write()`).

This way, if you call `write` on too much data, your class will write to the underlying stream until at most 64-bytes remain, and your subsequent call to `flush` will ensure those last few bytes actually get written to the Arduino.  At the end of the day, you also get a fully-Java-compliant `OutputStream` implementation, which is nice too.

***Edit***

I'm using 64-bytes simply because you stated that your Arduino can handle up to that many at a time.  Of course, this can be reduced if necessary, I'm just using "64" for convenience.

Comment: "then ping(), prior to buffering/writing any more data" - thing is,  `ping()` is intended to be called from the Arduino side (when receiving a signal on the `InputStream` from Arduino). The idea is that the Arduino is sending a `ping()` when it is ready to receive more bytes.

Comment: I see - your `write` method would need to block until it had received a ping from the Arduino.  I should have been more clear.  I was assuming that somehow, your Arduino would trigger a call to `ping()` when it was ready to receive more data.  In that case, your overridden `write()` method would block until `ping()` got called, and `ping()` wouldn't need to do anything other than release the `write` method so that it could continue writing data.

Comment: Nah, that's not quite what I want. I want every call to `write()` to buffer up bytes, and return immediately. No blocking here. Every time  `flush()` is called, 64 (or less) bytes from the buffer is written to the underlying stream. A `ping()` would cause the 64 next bytes (or less) to be written. OK, maybe I´m not strictly conforming to the specification of `OutputStream.flush()`.

Comment: Well...  okay... lol.  You could still conform to the spec though if you just had your flush() method block if it had too much data to send and needed to wait for a ping() call to push the next 64 bytes.  Maybe you have other reasons why you wouldn't want to do that, but in any case, I think you probably don't want to have the ability interleave calls to write() and flush() - that just seems inherently dangerous, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your `flush()` writes `WIRE_CAPACITY` = 25 bytes maximum in each call. You call it twice and total output is 50 bytes (assumming cp1252 encoding). I see nothing wrong with that.

Maybe you should be calling `flush()` inside `ping()`? Your test would then become basically:

```
@Test
public void testStream() throws IOException {
    final ArduinoDisplayOutputStream.ArduinoBufferedOutputStream stream = new ArduinoDisplayOutputStream.ArduinoBufferedOutputStream(System.out);
    stream.write("This is a very, very long string, which must be made even longer to demonstrate the problem".getBytes());
    stream.flush();
    stream.ping();
    stream.ping();
    ... // as many ping()s as written bytes / WIRE_CAPACITY
}
```

Comment: I don't see how calling `flush()` inside `ping()` would solve the problem? I modified my code to try it, and it gave the exact same result as before.

Comment: Your current code will not `flush()` the whole pending buffer automatically, just the next `WIRE_CAPACITY` bytes. If you put a `flush()` inside `ping()`, whenever the Arduino signals the `ping()`, the stream will automatically send the next `WIRE_CAPACITY` bytes (thus triggering another `ping()`, and so on until your buffer is empty). You can simulate this in your test by calling `ping()` multiple times. With your current code, if you just call `flush()`twice, you will just write 2 * `WIRE_CAPACITY` = 2 * 25 = 50 bytes maximum.

Comment: Ah yes, I agree that makes for cleaner code - I updated the question. But the problem still remains - no matter how many `ping()`s I send, the rest of the string is never printed.